# Python geopy geocoders.Google

Tags: python, google-maps, csv, geopy

I am trying to run a Python script using Geopy that creates a list of coordinates.
I have installed Geopy, and am running from Terminal on a Mac.

```
python
from geopy import geocoders
import csv
g_api_key = 'I HAVE ENTERED MY GOOGLE API HERE’
g = geocoders.Google(g_api_key)
```

I then get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Google'
```

Could my API key be wrong? Why is this happening? If I didn't receive this message, I would load the .csv next:

```
costcos = csv.reader(open('costcos-limited.csv'), delimiter=',')
next(costcos) #skip header
#print header
print "Address,City,State,Zip Code,Latitude,Longitude"
continue
full_addy = row[1] + "," + row[2] + "," + row[3] + "," + row[4]
try:
place, (lat, lng) = list(g.geocode(full_addy, exactly_one=False))[0]
print full_addy + "," + str(lat) + "," + str(lng)
except:
print full_addy + ",NULL,NULL"
```

Is this code correct, and is the 'continue' (above 'full_addy') necessary in this code? 
Finally, if I get help to make the 'geocoders.Google' work, and this script works, how do you run a Python script? I.e. I've been writing these commands into Terminal, how do I run the script on the final 'print full_addy + ",NULL,NULL"' line and save the output as costcos-geocoded.csv?

Thank you in advance for any help that comes my way...

Comment: I don't know `geopy` but shouldn't you use `geocoders.GoogleV3(g_api_key)` instead of `geocoders.Google(g_api_key)`? Which version of `geopy` are you using?

Comment: Yes, you're right. It then says: <geopy.geocoders.googlev3.GoogleV3 object at 0x10520d710>, which sounds good! On the next line, when I load the .csv file, how does it know where the .csv is? Do I need to cd (change directory) or something?

Comment: I've put the .csv file on my desktop

Comment: You should use whole path to that file. In windows it will be something like `C:/Users/.../Desktop/file.csv`, on linux `/home/user/.../Desktop/file.csv`, or you can put that .csv file in the directory where your script is, and use relative path (only `file.csv` in such case)

Comment: I entered: costcos = csv.reader(open(~/Desktop/costcos-limited.csv), delimiter=',')
This doesn't seem to work. I'm on a Mac. I'm entering the lines into Terminal rather than double-clicking on a completed .py script. Once I figure out the directory path, all I need to do is figure out how to run the script and save the output as a .csv.

Comment: You should not use `~` but full path `/home/username/Desktop/costcos-limited.csv`. If you are running python shell from terminal - the working directory should be where you run python shell. Check my updated answer about how to run python script.

Comment: When I right-click on the file and select its properties, it says its location is: '/Users/user/Desktop', so I've entered: costcos = csv.reader(open(/Users/user/Desktop/costcos-limited.csv), delimiter=',') but it says'SyntaxError: invalid syntax'. Sorry to bother you with this, I am very close to giving up but am so close! I may just try double-clicking on the example .py file I have and put the csv in the same folder and see if that works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Didn't you forgot to add quote marks ? `costcos = csv.reader(open('/Users/user/Desktop/costcos-limited.csv'), delimiter=',')`

Comment: Yes! So I managed to move to the next lines. 'continue' seemed to cause an error, so I just left it out, although it may have been missing a colon at second glance. The next line: 'full_addy = row[1] + "," + row[2] + "," + row[3] + "," + row[4]' returned a: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'row' is not defined'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `'module' object has no attribute 'Google'` error occurred because you are using new version of `geopy` which does not have `Google` class but `GoogleV3`, which allows to use API version 3.

Just use:

`g = geocoders.GoogleV3(g_api_key)`

To write a python script instead of writing code into python shell just save your code into `script.py` file and run it from terminal:

`python script.py`

or if you want to save the output of that script to a file:

`python script.py > output_file.txt`