# Geocode: Module has no attribute "google"

Tags: python, module, attributes, geocode

I know several have already asked similar questions but I'm a beginner and trying to figure this out for days and no luck yet.

I want to geocoder and execute geocoder.google command to get the latitude and longitude of the location but "google" attribute doesn't seem to be running in my Jupyter Notebook for some reason.

Package location:
Python36>Lib>site-packages>geocode, which contains a list of .py files such as **init**.py, and google.py.

```
import geocoder
from geocoder import google
g = geocoder.google('Mountain View, CA')

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-baacb41ba0bf> in <module>()
  1 import geocoder
  2 #from geocoder import google
  3 g = geocoder.google('Mountain View, CA')
  4 #g.latlng
  5 

AttributeError: module 'geocoder' has no attribute 'google'
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please don't post links to screenshots of the error, it should be contained as text in your question

Comment: Revised as texts, please advise what needs to be done.

Comment: pls include the version of geopy you're running. Also see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26281733/python-geopy-geocoders-google, new version of geopy which does not have Google class but GoogleV3.

Comment: Is it possible to use "Geocoder" module over "Geopy" module?

Comment: https://geocoder.readthedocs.io/api.html#install
Above link is for introduction of geocoder, followed the installation step by typing "pip install geocoder" in the cmd window. It loads the module but not a specific py file called "google" in this instance.

Comment: Try to run one of these tests https://github.com/DenisCarriere/geocoder/blob/master/tests/test_google.py ın your code if you still have problems with your installation is bad. Just create a venv and install pypi version of that package

Answer (score 0):

I happened to uninstall Anaconda and reinstall python and get this done.

Answer (score 0):

1.ensure execute

```
pip install geocoder
```

2.remove the statement

```
from geocoder import google
```

3.keep only one import statement

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import geocoder
    g = geocoder.google('Mountain View, CA')
    print(g)
```

4.result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are importing both `geocoder` and `geocoder.google`. So here's how to fix this.

Here's what you *can* do:

```py
from geocoder import google
g = google('Mountain View, CA')
# this code runs
```

Here's what *I* would do, but you don't have to:

```py
import geocoder as g
info = g.google('Mountain View, CA')
```

But you don't have to do this.

P.S. If this doesn't work, try ungrading pip and reinstalling the package.

```
python -m pip uninstall geocoder
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install geocoder
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest upgrading your pip:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

and then run the following command:

```
pip install geocoder
```